# Database handling by mutipl host

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using database in one server .I wanted to access that database from multiple location but issue is that when one access that data in the table no body can access those data.What will be that better way to handle?

Comment: *Why* can't the database handle multiple simultaneous accesses?

Comment: Are you taking about table level locking? You should be able to change it to use page or row level locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be giving more details about your problem

1. What RDMS do you use?
2. What is the transaction isolation level?
3. Are you performing any explicit table locking? If yes, what kind of locks are you acquiring?
4. Do you have synchronized methods in your app code?

It's rather hard to believe but it might be the case that your using **serializable** isolation level and that your transactions update the same table.